# OnRecordStart, line 2: SyntaxError: missing ) after condition

Tags: javascript

```
if (!AlreadyReadExternalFile ("T:\PRINT SHOP\WebCRD Templates\Mailing Labels\Office Address")
{
    ExternalData=new ExternalDataFileEx(LookupFile, "T:\PRINT SHOP\WebCRD Templates\Mailing Labels\Office Address,");
    AlreadyReadExternalFile = true;
    if (!ExternalData.valid)
    {
        var Message = "External file NOT found: " + LookupFile;
        Print(Message);
    }
    else
    {
        var Message = "External file found: " + LookupFile;
        Print(Message);
    }
```

I have no knowledge of writing code. I was told to replace a few items which I did and now the code doesn't seem to work. Can someone please direct me to what I'm missing.

Comment: First line is missing a closing `)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line should be this

```
if (!AlreadyReadExternalFile ("T:\PRINT SHOP\WebCRD Templates\Mailing Labels\Office Address"))
```

You were missing the closing parenthesis to the if statement. The first line has two opening parentheses which must be closed.

Comment: limelights - Thank you